# Getting some input from user and insert multiple table with Entity Framework

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I want to add some information into my database. The question is how can I post my inputs for 3 table at the same time? My tables are below. Let me clear that.

I have teachers and working hours and working days. I want that firstly I select the teacher name from dropdownlist,then select the day from dropdownlist and write working hours for example "09:00 - 17:00".
After that I submit these information I expectation is that seeing all these information can be added into database seperately and relationally.

```
Sample scenario: John Reese     Friday   09:00-17:00

                 Harold Finch   Monday   11:00-15:00
```

I am able to pull the teacher's names from database but at the same time in the same page I want to see that day's names.  After all these selecetions as I mentioned above, I wanna add all these informations.

[image: My Databese Scheme]

My create controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            var myTeacherList = (from teacher in db.Teachers.ToList()
                select new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = teacher.Firstname + teacher.Lastname,
                    Value = teacher.Id.ToString(),
                }).ToList();
            var myDayNameList = (from day in db.WeekDays.ToList()
                select new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = day.Name,
                    Value = day.Id.ToString(),
                }).ToList();


            ViewBag.TeacherId = myTeacherList;
            ViewBag.DayId = myDayNameList;
            return View();
        }
```

My Create Controller

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Appointment</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TeacherId, "Teacher Name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.Teacher.Id,(List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.TeacherId, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TeacherId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Hours,"Working Hour", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Hours, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Hours, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

[image: MSSQL Diagram]

Teacher.cs

```
namespace LanguageSchool.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Teacher
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Teacher()
        {
            this.Appointments = new HashSet<Appointment>();
            this.Classes = new HashSet<Class>();
            this.Languages = new HashSet<Language>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Firstname { get; set; }
        public string Lastname { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DateOfStart { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]

        public virtual ICollection<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]

        public virtual ICollection<Class> Classes { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]

        public virtual ICollection<Language> Languages { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Appointment.cs

```
namespace LanguageSchool.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Appointment
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]

        public Appointment()
        {
            this.WeekDays = new HashSet<WeekDay>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int TeacherId { get; set; }
        public string Hours { get; set; }

        public virtual Teacher Teacher { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]

        public virtual ICollection<WeekDay> WeekDays { get; set; }
    }
}
```

WeekDay.cs

```
namespace LanguageSchool.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class WeekDay
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]

        public WeekDay()
        {
            this.Class_WeekDay = new HashSet<Class_WeekDay>();
            this.Appointments = new HashSet<Appointment>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]

        public virtual ICollection<Class_WeekDay> Class_WeekDay { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]

        public virtual ICollection<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: To clarify, you want to save to multiple tables at the same time and also save multiple records at the same time?

Comment: @JerdineSabio Yes, sure. Actually I can add a teacher my database right now. If I can add during the teacher addition process, I can avoid getting extra code.

Comment: How is `Weekday` connected to `Appointment`? I don't see `AppointmentId` on `Weekday`.

Comment: I updated the question and added the mssql diagram scheme. @JerdineSabio

Comment: Oh okay, so in the end, we'll be inserting to `Appointment` and `Weekday_TeacherAppointment`, correct?

Comment: Yes, I actually want that I select a teacher and a day via dropdownlistfor and enter the working hour so that add the all these information into database.Ex: I select Teacher John and the day wednesday and enter the 09:00-15:00. after this process, I expec to see all these informations can be addedinto database relationally

Comment: In your models, what is the model name for Weekday_TeacherAppointment?

Comment: When I opened the model diagram, I was surprised and explored. Entity framewok ignored these middle tables. So the model does not have such a table. Notice, in the first diagram arrowheads have many(*) sign instead

Comment: can I see your Appointment and Weekday models? I need to see the code, thanks.

Comment: Sure, I edited.@JerdineSabio

Comment: added answer, please double check models and make sure the new model is added to database context

Comment: @JerdineSabio I will be working on your answer and I will reply. Thanks for now. I appreciate you. :)))

Comment: @JerdineSabio Thank you very much again. You helped me a lot. Hats off! :)))

Comment: Wow, it worked! You're welcome, thanks too!

Comment: Yeah. The problem was in my relations between tables as you mentioned.

Comment: @JerdineSabio If i don't bother you, can you take a look at my new question please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to make a ViewModel that contains all those properties so that the moment we do a POST request, they are all bound and we could access them for saving.

1. But first we need to modify your models and insert a class for the many to many table.

We need to remove `Weekday` from `Appointments` and
`Appointments` from `Weekday`.

Then replace them with `AppointmentWeekday`. **Be sure to run Migrations/Update-Database after this first step.**

```
public class Appointment{
   ...
   // REMOVE public virtual ICollection<WeekDay> WeekDays { get; set; }

   // Add this
   public virtual ICollection<AppointmentWeekday> AppointmentWeekdays {get;set;}
}

public class Weekday{
   ...
   // REMOVE public virtual ICollection<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }

   // Add this
   public virtual List<AppointmentWeekday> AppointmentWeekdays {get;set;}
}

// Add this
public class AppointmentWeekday{
   public int AppointmentId {get;set;}
   [ForeignKey("AppointmentId")]
   public virtual Appointment Appointment {get;set;}

   public int WeekdayId {get;set;}
   [ForeignKey("WeekdayId")]
   public virtual Weekday Weekday {get;set;}
}
```

2. Make the View Model with the necessary properties, I named it `TeacherAppointmentViewModel`.

```
public class TeacherAppointmentViewModel{
   public int TeacherId {get;set;}
   public int DayId {get;set;}
   public string Hours {get;set;}
}
```

3. Instantiate this in your controller and pass it to the view.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
   var myTeacherList = (from teacher in db.Teachers.ToList()
   select new SelectListItem
   {
      Text = teacher.Firstname + teacher.Lastname,
      Value = teacher.Id.ToString(),
   }).ToList();

   var myDayNameList = (from day in db.WeekDays.ToList()
   select new SelectListItem
   {
      Text = day.Name,
      Value = day.Id.ToString(),
   }).ToList();

   ViewBag.TeacherId = myTeacherList;
   ViewBag.DayId = myDayNameList;

   // instantiate
   TeacherAppointmentViewModel tvm = new TeacherAppointmentViewModel();

   // pass to the view
   return View(tvm);
}
```

4. Make your view use `TeacherAppointmentViewModel`.

```
@model TeacherAppointmentViewModel
```

5. Edit view, use the code below.

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Appointment</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TeacherId, "Teacher Name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.TeacherId,(List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.TeacherId, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TeacherId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.WeekdayId, "Day", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.WeekdayId,(List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.WeekdayId, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.WeekdayId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Hours,"Working Hour", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Hours, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Hours, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

6. Use controller action below, we need to assign the properties to `Appointment` and `AppointmentWeekday` then add to the db;

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(TeacherAppointmentViewModel tvm){

   // create appointment
   Appointment a = new Appointment();

   // assign teacher id and hours from viewmodel
   a.TeacherId = tvm.TeacherId;
   a.Hours = tvm.Hours;

   // save appointment
   db.Appointments.Add(a);
   db.SaveChanges();

   // create appointmentweekday
   AppointmentWeekday aw = new AppointmentWeekday();

   // assign properties
   // since we've saved the appointment, we could use a.AppointmentId

   aw.WeekdayId = tvm.WeekdayId;
   aw.AppointmentId = a.AppointmentId; // appointment from earlier

   // save appointmentweekday
   db.AppointmentWeekdays.Add(aw);
   db.SaveChanges();
}
```